# Как склоняется фамилия Олишевец

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Подскажите, как склоняется мужской вариант фамилии Олишевец?

Comment: @Olishevetc, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Олишевец
Олишевца
Олишевцу
Олишевца
Олишевцем
Олишевце

P.S. Если ударение на последнем слоге, то в творительном падеже "ОлишевцОм".